# missing angle markings

Tags: tikz-pgf

I just drew a graph and I would like to mark angle between two intersected line (you could see with this given MWE below). However, the arc (for marking the angle) is not appeared, though. It is even more weird as another image (within the same document) could show the angle marking. I'll give the code for the next image below the first one. Could someone tell me for a solution to fix this? If any, where did I miss?

**For detailed information :**

- I used `\pgfplotsset{compat=1.17}`
- Both used `\pgfplotsset{ticks=none}` setting. (Personal reasons)
- Background colour is **black** and the text is **white**

This is the image where the angle marking does not appear,

```
...
\pgfplotsset{ticks=none}
...
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=.5][line cap=round,line join=round,>=triangle 45,x=1.0cm,y=1.0cm]
\begin{axis}[
x=1.0cm,y=1.0cm,
axis lines=middle,
xlabel=$x$,
ylabel=$y$,
xmin=-7.2045675063146963,
xmax=5.420281689723229,
ymin=-8.835962675054054,
ymax=2.389508988491594,]
\clip(-7.2045675063146963,-8.835962675054054) rectangle (5.420281689723229,2.389508988491594);
\draw [shift={(0.8,-3.4)},line width=1.pt,color=qqwuqq,fill=qqwuqq,fill opacity=0.10000000149011612] (0,0) -- (-71.56505117707799:0.987578152218083) arc (-71.56505117707799:-26.565051177077986:0.987578152218083) -- cycle;
\draw [shift={(0.8,-3.4)},line width=1.pt,color=qqwuqq,fill=qqwuqq,fill opacity=0.10000000149011612] (0,0) -- (-116.56505117707799:0.987578152218083) arc (-116.56505117707799:-71.56505117707799:0.987578152218083) -- cycle;
\draw [line width=1.pt,domain=-7.2045675063146963:5.420281689723229] plot(\x,{(-5.--2.*\x)/1.});
\draw [line width=1.pt,domain=-7.2045675063146963:5.420281689723229] plot(\x,{(-1.-3.*\x)/1.});
\draw [line width=1.pt,domain=-7.2045675063146963:5.420281689723229] plot(\x,{(--6.--1.*\x)/-2.});                  
\draw[color=white] (-6.,0.25) node {$-6$};
\draw[color=white] (-0.3,-1.) node {$-1$};
\draw[color=white] (-0.3,-3.2) node {$-3$};
\draw[color=white] (-0.35,-5.) node {$-5$};
\node[color=white,rotate=-71.56505118] at (2.1,-6.6) {$3x + y + 1 = 0$};
\node[color=white,rotate=63.43494882] at (1.4,-1.6) {$y = 2x - 5$};
\draw[color=white] (1.2321540932847803,-3.8745390125525146) node {$\theta$};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Here is the snapshot for the image result

[image: First Image]

This is where the angle marking appear

```
\begin{tikzpicture}[line cap=round,line join=round,>=triangle 45,x=1.0cm,y=1.0cm]
\clip(-6.729809423412849,2.348340941072309) rectangle (3.9638031402979273,10.6029210327);
\draw [shift={(-6.,3.)},line width=1.pt,color=white,fill=qqwuqq,fill opacity=0.10000000149011612] (0,0) -- (0.:0.8) arc (0.:45.:0.8) -- cycle;
\draw [line width=1.pt] (-6.,7.)-- (1.,7.);
\draw [line width=1.pt] (1.,7.)-- (1.,3.);
\draw [line width=1.pt] (-6.,7.)-- (-6.,3.);
\draw [line width=1.pt] (-6.,3.)-- (1.,3.);
\draw [line width=1.pt] (-6.,3.)-- (1.,10.);
\draw [line width=1.pt] (-2.5,6.5)-- (1.,3.);
\draw [line width=1.pt] (1.,7.)-- (-0.5,8.5);
\draw [dashed, line width=1.pt] (1.,7.) -- (3.,5.);
\draw [dashed, line width=1.pt] (3.,5.) -- (1.,3.);
\draw [dashed, line width=1.pt] (1.,3.) -- (3.,3.);
\draw [fill=gray] (-6.,7.) circle (2.pt);
\draw[color=white] (-6.3,7.25) node {$D$};
\draw[color=white] (-6.3,2.7) node {$A$};
\draw [fill=gray] (-6.,3.) circle (2.pt);
\draw [fill=gray] (1.,3.) circle (2.pt);
\draw[color=white] (1.3,2.7) node {$B$};
\draw[color=white] (1.3,7.25) node {$C$};
\draw [fill=gray] (1.,7.) circle (2.pt);
\draw [fill=gray] (1.,10.) circle (2.pt);
\draw[color=white] (0.75,10.25) node {$E$};
\draw [fill=gray] (-2.5,6.5) circle (2.pt);
\draw[color=white] (-2.7,6.7) node {$P$};
\draw[color=white] (-5.48,3.22) node {$\alpha$};
\draw [fill=gray] (-0.5,8.5) circle (2.pt);
\draw[color=white] (-0.75,8.75) node {$Q$};
\draw[color=white] (3.3,5.) node {$P'$};
\draw[color=white] (3.3,3.) node {$B'$};
\end{tikzpicture}
```

Here is for the second image

[image: Second Image]

The angle marking I want is the arc that contains `$\alpha$` inside

Comment: Not related but I suggest you clean your code since it obviously comes from a geometric drawing software (Geogebra-like) with all the approximative values and all the dots for integers... Not very user-friendly. More related, you could have a look to the `tkz-euclide` library, which allows you to do everything you neeed on-the-fly, very easily.

Comment: @SebGlav Do you mean by reading the package documentation? By the way, thank you very much for the info.

Comment: I meant practicing this package. It gives a lot of very useful shortcuts when drawing geometrics (lines, circles, intersections between them, angles, etc.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that your problem is probably the color. In the second drawing you explicit draw the angle in white, but not in the first.

There are many ways to put the angles. With an arc, like you do; with a clip, like the following example, with angles library; etc. In this case a clip is very simple.

This is my example. I changed colors and coordinates, to avoid to put so many digits:

```
\documentclass[border=2mm]{standalone}
\usepackage   {tikz}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[line cap=round]
\def\xmin{-7}
\def\xmax {5}
\def\ymin{-9}
\def\ymax {2}
\draw[thick,-latex] (\xmin,0) -- (\xmax,0) node[above left]  {$x$};
\draw[thick,-latex] (0,\ymin) -- (0,\ymax) node[below right] {$y$};
\clip (\xmin,\ymin) rectangle (\xmax,\ymax);
\draw[red] (-5,-15) -- (10,15) node[above, midway, shift={(-2,0)}, sloped] {$y=2x-5$};
\draw[red] (-5, 14) -- (5,-16) node[above, midway, shift={( 6,0)}, sloped] {$3x+y+1=0$};
\draw[red] (-8,  1) -- (8, -7);
\node at (-6,0) [above]      {$-6$};
\node at (0,-1) [left]       {$-1$};
\node at (0,-3) [below left] {$-3$};
\node at (0,-5) [left]       {$-5$};
% angle theta
\clip (8,-7) -- (0.8,-3.4) -- (5,-16);
\draw[blue] (0.8,-3.4) circle (0.6);
\node[blue] at (1.4,-4.1) {$\theta$};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I see. However, it looks weird after I change the color as it still doesn't work at all. Moreover, your code works well one mine (+ I've changed it to white and it works, though). Thank you so much.